# It is possible to create a simple IDE with gtk or qt less than a month?

Tags: qt, gtk

In my school, we have a project where you have to dev a c program which works as a GPS but in a console. We must define room in x-y position and path from room-X to room-Y and calculate the best travel from point A to point B.

But that's not on this point I want help.

Because this project is not hard (already done), I would like to create an simple IDE where you could edit file, edit a view list of room and path, and get a representation with openGL of the best travel compare to the others. Knowing that I have no (or really little) experience on GTK+ or QT, is this possible to do this soft in less a month. I know C and a bit of cpp and I already tried 1 soft on GTK+ with only one widget and i'm trying actually QT 5.6 with QT Quick and QT Application.

I'm not very experienced, I have found some docs on QT (official Docs but didn't understand everything) but much example and really few docs on GTK+, is there others docs/tutorial which are not official (on QT and GTK)?

And for a beginner as me, do I really have to venture into the development of software like this?

Comment: This question is really hard to anwser since it depends on a number of factors. How much time you will put in. Your experience and skills as a developer, how much less than a month? etc etc.

Comment: concentrate on a good implementation of the main problem instead of a fancy ui.

Comment: Main problem is already done, based on Dijkstra's algorythm

It's been 2 years I code in C, tried cpp in few projects, I really don't count times of work so time is not really a problem, I work approximately 90-100 hours a week and I've got approximatively 3 weeks to a month ! I know it's difficult to answer this question, but I am lost on the workload what I will have

Answer (score 2):

If you have FUN AND TIME to dig into, it's probably done in a week or less. For me this was true with QtWidgets. Don't now how it would be for me with QtQuick but probably the same. (90-100h per week is plenty of time. just start !)

Comment: It's exactly what I mean, I have time and I want to explore something else than C console program ! :) I already tried, I will continue.. :